# Evaluate a Postfix Expression Using a Singly Linked List

Tags: java, linked-list, stack, postfix-notation

I'm writing a program that asks the user for a postfix expression, and then outputs the result to the expression. I am attempting to do this using a Singly Linked List, and using the Adapter Pattern to create a stack.

The code for the `SinglyLinkedList` class, the `LinkedStack` class, and the `Stack` implementation are all straight out of a Data Structures book that I own. So the `SinglyLinkedListTest` class is the only one that has my own code in it (and has errors).

I've written a program that simply uses a stack to evaluate a postfix expression before, but I'm getting confused  this time with the extra classes included.

I'm sure I have a ton of errors, but the most obvious ones to me are in my `SinglyLinkedListTest` class, every time I push a value onto the stack. I know the issue is that I am attempting to push Objects and characters onto the stack instead of the arguments that match push(E e), but I don't know how to alter my code to make this work.

Any suggestions or input would be greatly appreciated.

**Here is my Stack Implementation:**

```
package PostFix;

public interface Stack<E> 
{
    int size();

    boolean isEmpty();

    void push(E e);

    E pop();
}
```

**Here is my LinkedStack class:**

```
package PostFix;

public class LinkedStack <E> implements Stack<E>
{
    private SinglyLinkedList<E> list = new SinglyLinkedList<>();

    public LinkedStack()
    {

    }

    public int size()
    {
        return list.size();
    }

    public boolean isEmpty()
    {
        return list.isEmpty();
    }

    public void push(E e)
    {
        list.addFirst(e);
    }

    public E pop()
    {
        return list.removeFirst();
    }
}
```

**Here is my SinglyLinkedList class:**

```
package PostFix;

public class SinglyLinkedList<E>
{
    private static class Node<E>
    {
        private E element;
        private Node<E> next;

        public Node(E e, Node<E> n)
        {
            element = e;
            next = n;
        }

        public E getElement()
        {
            return element;
        }

        public Node<E> getNext()
        {
            return next;
        }       
    }

    private Node<E> head = null;
    private Node<E> tail = null;
    private int size = 0;

    public SinglyLinkedList()
    {

    }

    public int size()
    {
        return size;
    }

    public boolean isEmpty()
    {
        return size == 0;
    }

    public void addFirst(E e)
    {
        head = new Node<>(e, head);

        if (size == 0)
        {
            tail = head;
        }
        size++;
    }

    public E removeFirst()
    {
        if (isEmpty())
        {
            return null;
        }
        E answer = head.getElement();
        head = head.getNext();
        size--;

        if (size == 0)
        {
            tail = null;
        }
        return answer;
    }
}
```

**Here is my *final* SinglyLinkedListTest class:**

```
package PostFix;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SinglyLinkedListTest 
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Double num1, num2, answer;
        char c;

        Stack<Double> stack = new LinkedStack<>();
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter the expression you would like to evaluate: ");
        String someString = input.nextLine();

        for (int index = 0; index < someString.length(); index++)
        {
            c = someString.charAt(index);

            if (Character.isDigit(c))
            {
                stack.push((double)Character.digit(c, 10));
            }
            else if (c == '+')
            {
                num2 = stack.pop();
                num1 = stack.pop();
                answer = num1+num2;
                stack.push(answer);
            }
            else if (c == '-')
            {
                num2 = stack.pop();
                num1 = stack.pop();
                answer = num1-num2;
                stack.push(answer);
            }
            else if (c == '*')
            {
                num2 = stack.pop();
                num1 = stack.pop();
                answer = num1*num2;
                stack.push(answer);
            }
            else if (c == '/')
            {
                num2 = stack.pop();
                num1 = stack.pop();
                answer = num1/num2;
                stack.push(answer);
            }     
        }
        System.out.println("The result is: " + stack.pop());
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: @EJP - In my SinglyLinkedListTest class, I am attempting to push elements onto the stack, but the arguments I am trying to push are not the same arguments defined in the push(E e) method (I am trying to push objects and characters onto the stack instead of the E e). How do I make the arguments match up, or how do I alter the code in order to successfully push these elements onto the stack?

Comment: Define 'are not the same arguments', 'make the arguments match up', ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Stack<String> buffer = new LinkedStack<>();
```

- Poor name: call it `stack`.
- You've declared it as `Stack<String>` but you're pushing `chars`:

  ```
   buffer.push(someString.charAt(index));
  ```

  and `Objects`:

  ```
  buffer.push(answer);
  ```

  and popping `ints`:

  ```
  num1 = buffer.pop();
  ```
- You are never either pushing or popping strings.

Just make up your mind. You should be pushing and popping `ints`, or `longs`, or `doubles`, or `BigDecimals`, depending on what precision you need.

**EDIT**

```
buffer.push((double)c);
```

is invalid. You're pushing the ASCII value, not the numeric value it corresponds to. You need

```
buffer.push((double)Character.digit(c, 10));
```

You also need an `else` after each `if` block: if the character is a digit, it won't be a `+`, and if it's a `+` it won't be a `-`, etc.

Comment: I posted the edited code up above. That got rid of all of my errors, and my program runs now. However, I am getting wrong answers. Subtraction works every time, but all of the other operands are incorrect every time. Here are some answers I am getting: 63+ = 105, 63* = 2754, 63/ = 1.0588, 54+=105, 54* = 2756, 54/ = 1.0192

Comment: Thank you so much. I posted the final code. It works perfectly!